# Selenium can't find element (xpath)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

So Im trying to click this element:

> //*[@id="ember1720"]

But Selenium tells me it can't find it. Im doing the operation like so: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember1720"]').click()`

I've tried the same program on the official python website and it works perfectly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the element has been loaded correctly:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
...


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
  EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="ember1720"]""")))
```

or maybe:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
  EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="ember1720"]""")))
```

Alternatively, try to find the element by id:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ember1720').click()
```

I've faced issues in the past where I could find the element by its ID but not by xpath.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's your exact problem, but depending on IDs like this, which seems to be auto generated are not a good practice.
Please read [my blog post](https://medium.com/@arnonaxelrod/best-practices-for-choosing-locators-for-selenium-8946ecf0abf5) for the best practices for choosing the best locator.